# Windsor IoC DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, dbcontext

I am trying to add Windsor Castle 3.3.0 IoC with my MVC 5 project dbcontext (EF 6) and have had a look at many articles, but I can't figure out how to do it and keep running into the problem of getting the following error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

This error only seems to occur once the first page has loaded and then I try to load subsequent pages

This is my code:

**Context Interface**

```
public interface IMyContext
{
    IDbSet<DBProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public MyContext ()
        : base("Name=MyDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public IDbSet<DBProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public sealed class CatalogueDAL : ICatalogueDAL
{
    private IMyContext _dbContext;

    public CatalogueDAL(IMyContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext= dbContext;
    }

    public ICollection<DBProduct> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return _dbContext.Products
                .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                .ToList();
    }
}


public class CatalogueHelper : ICatalogueHelper
{
    private ICategoryDAL _categoryDAL;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public CatalogueHelper(ICatalogueDAL catalogueDAL)
    {
        _catalogueDAL = catalogueDAL;
        CreateMapper();
    }

    public ICollection<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return _mapper.Map<ICollection<DBProduct>, ICollection<Product>>(_catalogueDAL.GetAllProducts());
    }

    private void CreateMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateProductMap();
        });

        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }
}


public class LandingPageController : Controller
{
    private ICatalogueHelper _helper;

    public LandingPageController(ICatalogueHelper helper)
    {
        _helper = helper;
    }

    public ActionResult AllProducts()
    {
        return View(_helper.GetAllProducts());
    }
}
```

**Castle Initialiser**

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
container.Register(Component.For<ICatalogueDAL>().ImplementedBy<CatalogueDAL>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
container.Register(Component.For<ICatalogueHelper>().ImplementedBy<CatalogueHelper>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

If I remove the IoC and put a `using(var context = new MyContext())` in the `GetAllProducts`, it will work fine but that seems to against the point?

How do I change this to use IoC on the dbContext.

I have tried just using the MyContext (instead of the interface) and registering that with

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyContext>().ImplementedBy<MyContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

And this seems to work better, but when I load two pages at the same time, the one that starts second will always get the following error message:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Having searched both these errors, I cannot figure out how to apply it to my solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is ICatalogueHelper? Can you share top resolver (eg: action method).

Comment: @MaDeRkAn sorry, have added the catalogue helper to the question

Comment: One more thing can you share where are u resolving `ICatalogueHelper` in action ?

Comment: @MaDeRkAn have added the controller that calls the helper

Comment: Can you change ICollection<DBProduct> GetAllProducts to IEnumerable<DBProduct> GetAllProducts and try.